# No logro llamar mi funcion desde otro archivo en js usando ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Quiero mandar a llamar la funcion insertar pero cuando lo pongo asi `'candidato/insertar'` pero cuando le pongo `'Candidato.php/candidato/insertar'` sale otra cosa diferente. No se si sea problema de la ruta estoy trabajando con Visual studio code

**El problema es que desde otra pc funciona correctamente**

Donde se encuetra la funcion es `Entec\application\controllers\Candidato.php\insert()`

lo que manda `base_url('');` simplemente concatena la direccion que le mandas y saldria esto: `localhost://Entec/candidato/insertar`

```
var urlNuevo = "<?php echo base_url('candidato/insertar'); ?>";

$.ajax({              
            url: urlNuevo,
            type: "POST",  
            data: form = new FormData($('#frmNuevoCandidato')[0]),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {                            
                    if (data.status) {
                        toastr.error('El registro se ha guardado correctamente.', '', {positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width', containerId: 'toast-top-full-width', progressBar: true});
                    } else {
                        toastr.success('El registro se ha guardado correctamente', '', {positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width', containerId: 'toast-top-full-width', progressBar: true});
                    }
                },
                error:
                    function (XmlHttpError, error, description) {
                        console.log(XmlHttpError.responseText);
                }
        });
```

Comment: estas almacenando una url de php directo al javascript???

Comment: Edite la pregunta a ver si me puedo dar a entender mejor 
@ArcanisGK507

Comment: @xztrece puede ser que funcione en un navegador con una version diferente y en otro no, entonces puede deberse a las versiones del navegador pero pues no se, igual nunca es bueno hacer lo que estas haciendo.

Comment: @Riven Como seria la mejor forma de llamar una funcion de php con Js al suprimir un botton

Comment: @xztrece la respuesta es no hacerlo, no mezcles ni trates de mezclar php con JS, trata de manter por lo menos lo que es el JS y el PHP por aparte, si algo he aprendido de eso es que solo trae problemas, dolores de cabeza codigo desorganizado y es mas dificil manter todo, entonces debes replantear el usar PHP ahi, en cambio de eso lo que haria seria crear un archivo de rutas en JS y llamarlo en el script, si quieres te puedo mostrar como, pero por mi parte no haria lo de la ruta mostrandola con el php.